# Vite proxy option does not rewrite the url of the axios instance

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, vite

I have a frontend run at 127.0.0.1:8080 and a backend run at 127.0.0.1:8081.

I use vite proxy to deal with CORS.

Here is my config.

```
// vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
    ...
    server: {
    port: 8080,
    cors: true,
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8081/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => { return path.replace(/^\/api/, '') }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```
//server.ts
const server = axios.create({
    baseURL: '/api',
    timeout: 5000,
});

...

export default server;
```

For example, I want to get `127.0.0.1:8081/user/login` ,when I use

`server.get('/user/login') ...`

It get `127.0.0.1:8080/api/user/login` instead of `127.0.0.1:8081/user/login`

```
console.log(path): /api/user/login
console.log(path.replace(/^\/api/, '')): /user/login
```

Comment: What's "it" in "It get"? Please, describe the problem in details. It could be that your expectations are wrong